# How can I overload the << operator so I can write the data of an object to a file?

Tags: c++

I have an object of type piggyBank and I need to write data of this object into a file and then read it. I am aware of how to write/read to a text file but how can I overload the << operator so I can write data about the object into a file?

My code for the class here:

*piggyBank.h*

```
#include <string>
#ifndef PIGGYBANK_H
#define PIGGYBANK_H

class PiggyBank
{
 private:
        std::string owner; 
        int balance; 
        bool broken; 
        int id;
        static int nrOfObjects;
    public:
        PiggyBank(void);
        PiggyBank(std::string name);
        std::string getOwnerName() const;
        void setOwnerName(std::string name);
        bool isBroken() ;
        int getBalance(int & amount) ;


};



#endif /* PIGGYBANK_H */
```

*piggyBank.cpp*

```
#include "PiggyBank.h"
#include "readWrite.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int PiggyBank::nrOfObjects = 0; // outside constructor


PiggyBank::getNrOfObjects(){

    return nrOfObjects;

}

PiggyBank::PiggyBank(void){
    {this->owner="";this->balance=0;this->broken=false;}
     id = ++nrOfObjects;

}


PiggyBank::PiggyBank(std::string name, int startBalance){
     {this->owner=name;this->balance=startBalance;this->broken=false;}
     id = ++nrOfObjects;
}

string PiggyBank::getOwnerName() const{
    return this->owner;
}
void PiggyBank::setOwnerName(string name){
    this->owner = name;
}
bool PiggyBank::isBroken() {
    return this->broken;
}

int PiggyBank::getBalance(int & amount) {
    if(!broken){
        amount = balance;
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `<< operator` to be a `friend` to the class and to `return ostream&`.
Here is a simple example to get an idea about how it works.

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const PiggyBank& obj)
{
   // For example something like this
   os << "Information that you want to output to the file:\n";
   os << "Owner: " << obj.owner << "\n";
   return os;
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
PiggyBack obj;
ofstream fout("file.txt");

// also check to see if the file opened correctly
if(fout.fail())
{
   cout << "File failed to open\n";
   return 0;
}
fout << obj;
// now you have written the owner information onto the file as well as the message before it
// inside the  operator<< overload

// close the resource at the end
fout.close();
```

The cool part is that you can use it to print to the console too by changing `fout` to be `cout`.
For example:

```
cout << obj; // will print to the console
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved my problem. I just have a small question: Do I have to overload also the istream if I want to read the written data about the object?

Comment: No problem. Yes, you can do this, too. When you overload it you will be able to read the file and store the information back into your object. Also you will be able to use cin to do the same.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help!

Answer (score 3):

Very simple. Overload the inserter operator. Write this into your class:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const PiggyBank& pb) {
    return os << pb.owner << . . .   // Whatever you want
```

Then you can use the inserter operator as for any other data type:

```
int main() {

    PiggyBank pb;

    if (std::ofstream os("FileName"); os) {
        os << pb << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot.